# How can I check the existence of attributes and tags in XML before parsing?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, conditional-statements, elementtree

I'm parsing an XML file via Element Tree in python and and writing the content to a cpp file.

The content of children tags will be variant for different tags.  For example first event tag has party tag as child but second event tag doesn't have.

- How can I check whether a tag exists or not before parsing?
- Children has value attribute in 1st event tag but not in second. How can I check whether an attribute exists or not before taking it's value.

Currently my code throws an error for non existing party tag and sets a "None" attribute value for the second children tag.

```xml
<main>
  <event>
    <party>Big</party>
    <children type="me" value="3"/>
  </event>

  <event>
    <children type="me"/>
  </event>

</main>
```

Code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('party.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for event in root.findall('event'):
    parties = event.find('party').text
    children = event.get('value')
```

I want to check the tags and then take their values.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If a tag doesn't exist, `.find()` indeed returns `None`. Simply test for that value:

```
for event in root.findall('event'):
    party = event.find('party')
    if party is None:
        continue
    parties = party.text
    children = event.get('value')
```

You already use `.get()` on event to test for the `value` the attribute; it returns `None` as well if the attribute does not exist.

Attributes are stored in the `.attrib` dictionary, so you can use standard Python techniques to test for the attribute explicitly too:

```
if 'value' in event.attrib:
    # value attribute is present.
```

Comment: @Martjin Pieters   You mentioned if party is None:                   How will I write in Python if i wish to write something like             -- If party!= None:

Comment: @Abhishek: `if party is not None`. See [python comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning how to check for attributes. Very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.8, we can use the walrus operator `:=` here to "simplify" the checking process. With an if statement, we check if the tag or attribute exists and proceed only if it does.

```py
tree = ET.parse('party.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for event in root.findall('event'):
    if (party := event.find('party')) is not None:   # <--- check if `party` tag exists
        parties = party.text
        print(parties)
    if (children := event.get('value')) is not None: # <--- check if `value` attribute exists
        print(children)
```