# How to check if a specific child is there in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have to check if an element has a specific child or not.
I tried hasattr() and it is not working

Ex: I have an xml, where frame is an element.  I have a large no. of elements 'frame'. signal and signalgroup are children and both are optional.  I want to check if a particular frame has a child signalgroup or not.

Please let me know how to check.

**UPDATE :**

I don't know which library, but I am using Symtavision software to parse the xml and run python script.

I have attached the piece of code that I am using:
frame has chilren 'Signal and Signalgroup'.  A particular frame may have both the children or either one of them.  I want to check if a frame has child 'Signalgroup' or not.

```
frames = system.getElements('Frame')

Signalgroups = system.getElements('Signalgroup')

for frame in frames:

     if(hasattr (frame.Signalgroup) == True):
          #some task
     else:
          #some task
```

Comment: What library are you using to parse the XML? Do you have some code to show?

Comment: There isn't enough info here, but you might want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568126/how-can-i-check-the-existence-of-attributes-and-tags-in-xml-before-parsing) out.

Comment: Please provide more information and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); What library are you using? Please show us a sample of your code.

Comment: I don't know which library, but I am using Symtavision software to parse the xml and run python script.

I have attached the piece of code that I am using: frame has chilren 'Signal and Signalgroup'. A particular frame may have both the children or either one of them. I want to check if a frame has child 'Signalgroup' or not.

frames = system.getElements('Frame')

Signalgroups = system.getElements('Signalgroup')

for frame in frames:

 if(hasattr (frame.Signalgroup) == True):
      #some task
 else:
      #some task

Comment: @AnanthaKrishna you can always edit your question to add more information (instead of posting new info as answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
frames = system.getElements("Frame")

for frame in frames:    
    if(len(frame.getChildren("SignalGroup")) > 0):
        print "Got some SignalGroup"
    else:
        print "No SignalGroup"
```

The signal groups are children of the frames. 
Btw: You can navigate to parents with element.getParents(...). 
I recommend you change the title of your question because it is not a pure python question but more a Symtavision (SymTA/S) API question. Cheers Chris