# Extracting value from XML value only if available

Tags: python

Newbie here, trying to extract values from tags inside XML file: docid, year, citedWork. However, not all the entries contain citedWork tag.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Wjp.png)

At the moment, i received:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Any suggestions on how to incorporate this condition into the script? Thanks!

```
for element in root.findall(".//return/references"):
list_nodes=[]

if count == 0:
    doc_id= element.find('docid').tag
    result.append(doc_id)

    year= element.find('year').tag
    result.append(year)

    cit_title= element.find('citedTitle').tag
    result.append(cit_title)

    cit_work= element.find('citedWork').tag
    result.append(cit_work)

    CSV_writer.writerow(result)
    count = +1

doc_id= element.find('docid').text
list_nodes.append(doc_id)

year= element.find('year').text
list_nodes.append(year)

cit_title= element.find('citedTitle').text
list_nodes.append(cit_title)

cit_work= element.find('citedWork').text
list_nodes.append(cit_work)    


CSV_writer.writerow(list_nodes)
```

xml_csv.close()

Comment: Check this out!. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568126/how-can-i-check-the-existence-of-attributes-and-tags-in-xml-before-parsing

Comment: thank you both for pointing me to the right direction! much appreciate it, it works now

Answer (score 1):

```
cit_work= element.find('citedWork').tag
cit_work= element.find('citedWork').text
```

For these cases, if you anticipate that 'citedWork' may not be present, you can check if the return value of `find` is not `None` before you try to access any of its attributes.

```
cit_work_elem = element.find('citedWork')
if cit_work_elem:
    cit_work = cit_work_elem.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes,

```
cit_work= element.find('citedWork').text
except:
   cit_work= None
```

If it is not there in xml file, it will be None. Try this!