# Trying to check if a tag exists in XML before parsing

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I need to check the existence of certain tags in an XML file before parsing it; I'm using Element Tree in Python. Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568126/how-can-i-check-the-existence-of-attributes-and-tags-in-xml-before-parsing), I tried writing this:

```
tgz_xml = f"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/utils/oa/oa.fcgi?id=PMC8300416" 
response = urllib.request.urlopen(tgz_xml).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(response)


for OA in tree.findall('OA'):
  records = OA.find('records')
  if records is None:
    print('records missing')
  else:
    print('records found')
```

I need to check if the "records" tag exists. I don't get an error, but this doesn't print out anything. What did I do wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing this XML document variable `tree` already points to element `OA`, so when searching for this element expression `tree.findall('OA')` returns an empty list and loop isn't executed. Remove that line and code will be executed:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
from urllib.request import urlopen

tgz_xml = f"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/utils/oa/oa.fcgi?id=PMC8300416" 
with urlopen(tgz_xml) as conn:
  response = conn.read()
  tree = ET.fromstring(response)

  records = tree.find('records')
  if records is None:
    print('records missing')
  else:
    print('records found')
```